# SQL program Permission Errors

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a table and drop foreign keys and tables in the beginning. If I do not drop Foreign Keys, It works fine, but when I add the code, it gives me the error, saying that I do not have permission to the database. Can someone please check/tweak my SQL code? It might be an issue of re arranging the foreign key statements, but I have tried different combinations with no result.

```
USE master ;
GO
CREATE DATABASE Prop1;
GO

USE Prop1;

GO

ALTER TABLE LEASE DROP CONSTRAINT FK_LEASE_CLIENT
ALTER TABLE LEASE DROP CONSTRAINT FK_LEASE_PROPERTY_FOR_RENT
ALTER TABLE property_for_rent DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PROPERTY_FOR_RENT_BRANCH
ALTER TABLE property_for_rent DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PROPERTYFORRENTPRIVATEOWNER
ALTER TABLE registration DROP CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTRATION_BRANCH
ALTER TABLE registration DROP CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTRATION_CLIENT
ALTER TABLE registration DROP CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTRATION_STAFF
ALTER TABLE staff DROP CONSTRAINT FK_STAFF_BRANCH
ALTER TABLE viewing DROP CONSTRAINT FK_VIEWING_CLIENT
ALTER TABLE viewing DROP CONSTRAINT FK_VIEWING_PROPERTY_FOR_RENT


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.viewing') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.viewing
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.lease') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.lease
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.property_for_rent') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.property_for_rent
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.registration') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.registration
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.staff') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.staff
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.private_owner') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.private_owner
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.client') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.client
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.branch') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.branch

CREATE TABLE branch(
   branchno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   street varchar(100) NULL,
   city varchar(20) NULL,
   postcode varchar(10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   branchno )) ;

CREATE TABLE client(
   clientno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   fname varchar(8) NULL,
   lname varchar(8) NULL,
   address varchar(35) NULL,
   tel_no varchar(14) NULL,
   pref_type char(6) NULL,
   max_rent int NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   clientno )) ;

CREATE TABLE lease(
   lease_no varchar(6) NOT NULL,
   property_no varchar(5) NULL,
   client_no varchar(5) NULL,
   rent int NULL,
   payment_method char(7) NULL,
   deposit int NULL,
   paid char(1) NULL,
   rent_start date NULL,
   rent_finish date NULL,
   duratn bigint NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   lease_no ));


CREATE TABLE private_owner(
   ownerno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   fname varchar(20) NULL,
   lname varchar(20) NULL,
   address varchar(50) NULL,
   tel_no varchar(14) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   ownerno ));


CREATE TABLE property_for_rent(
   propertyno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   street varchar(15) NULL,
   city varchar(10) NULL,
   postcode varchar(6) NULL,
   type char(7) NULL,
   rooms tinyint NULL,
   rent int NULL,
   ownerno varchar(5) NULL,
   staffno varchar(5) NULL,
   branchno varchar(5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   propertyno )) ;


CREATE TABLE registration(
   clientno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   branchno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   staffno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   datejoined date NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   clientno ,   branchno ,   staffno )) ;


CREATE TABLE staff(
   staffno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   fname varchar(15) NULL,
   lname varchar(15) NULL,
   position varchar(15) NULL,
   sex char(1) NULL,
   dob date NULL,
   salary decimal(7, 2) NULL,
   branchno varchar(5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   staffno ));


CREATE TABLE viewing(
   clientno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   propertyno varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   viewdate date NULL,
   comments varchar(200) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (   clientno ,   propertyno )) ;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO branch (branchno, street, city, postcode) VALUES ('B008', '12 Paul St', 'Preston', 'PR30JB');
INSERT INTO branch (branchno, street, city, postcode) VALUES ('B009', '32 Elizabeth St', 'Burmingham', 'BB17JE');
INSERT INTO branch (branchno, street, city, postcode) VALUES ('B010', '24 Koleen Dr', 'Manchester', 'KM41SA');

INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR78', 'George', 'Clinto', '55 St Louis Dr London JW10FR', '0121-773-3325', 'House ', 500);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR79', 'Muhammad', 'Aslam', '10 Queens Rd London KW40FM', '0171-213-2625', 'House ', 700);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR80', 'Sea', 'Hampto', '69 Rosco St Burmingham BI21KL', '0565-773-3032', 'Flat ', 300);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR81', 'Cyrus', 'Azarbod', '6 Skyline Dr London IN15ZZ', '0181-362-9325', 'House ', 800);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR82', 'Leo', 'Russel', '214 Terrible Dr Glasgow GW18PR', '0891-448-5569', 'Flat ', 450);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR83', 'Sameul', 'Sutto', '16 Moscut St Preston PC18JK', '0607-524-4532', 'Flat ', 500);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR84', 'Lyndi', 'Clinto', '50 Ceasar Bld London JZ10LR', '0171-793-7325', 'House ', 750);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR85', 'Kathree', 'Joshue', '77 Hoffman Dr Manchester MN48NB', '0525-854-4178', 'House ', 900);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR86', 'Julia', 'Roberts', '707 Rockford Dr London LK51VD', '0420-568-8544', 'House ', 1500);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR87', 'Michael', 'Jackso', '14 Madona Dr Preston DW11FY', '0414-552-6632', 'House ', 1200);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR88', 'George', 'Simpso', '25 Charles Dr London YN10BR', '0181-798-7325', 'Flat ', 850);
INSERT INTO client (clientno, fname, lname, address, tel_no, pref_type, max_rent) VALUES ('CR89', 'Fredo', 'Sati', '7 Nitro Dr London JK89YE', '0181-507-5151', 'Flat ', 550);

INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10087', 'PG76', 'CR78', 400, 'Cheque ', 800, 'Y','1995-03-02', '1999-10-31', NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10088', 'PG76', 'CR83', 400, 'Master ', 800, 'Y', '1999-11-01', '2002-09-30',NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10091', 'PG58', 'CR83', 500, 'Cash ', 900, 'Y', '2002-10-15','2003-01-15',NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10093', 'PG74', 'CR79', 600, 'Master ', 1200, 'Y', '1998-01-01', '1999-09-30',NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10095', 'PG15', 'CR84', 700, 'Cheque ', 1400, 'Y', '1995-04-15', '2003-03-15',NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10096', 'PG57', 'CR81', 750, 'Visa ', 1500, 'Y', '1996-01-01','2001-05-30',NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10100', 'PG56', 'CR87', 1200, 'Cash ', 2400, '', '2001-12-01', '2003-02-28',NULL);
INSERT INTO lease (lease_no, property_no, client_no, rent, payment_method, deposit, paid, rent_start, rent_finish, duratn) VALUES ('10101', 'PG59', 'CR86', 1400, 'Visa ', 3000, 'Y', '1997-11-01', '2001-11-30',NULL);

INSERT INTO private_owner (ownerno, fname, lname, address, tel_no) VALUES ('CO51', 'Blair', 'Steve', '2 Style Dr London JZ43KL', '0181-750-2551');
INSERT INTO private_owner (ownerno, fname, lname, address, tel_no) VALUES ('CO63', 'Kare', 'Salem', '14 Janet St Bristol BR43KL', '0121-750-6513');
INSERT INTO private_owner (ownerno, fname, lname, address, tel_no) VALUES ('CO64', 'Teetz', 'Alle', '2 Lookup Dr Manchester GA43', '0131-730-4002');
INSERT INTO private_owner (ownerno, fname, lname, address, tel_no) VALUES ('CO65', 'Leo', 'Russel', '15 Cicero St Bristol BR21UT', '0121-631-6262');

INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG15', '11 Arago', 'Manchester', 'SA32DC', 'House ', 4, 700, 'CO51', 'SG17', 'B008');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG56', '1 Jackson Ht', 'Manchester', 'MA32DC', 'House ', 6, 1200, 'CO51', 'SA81', 'B009');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG57', '10 Hamilton DR', 'Manchester', 'LO32VC', 'Flat ', 5, 700, 'CO64', 'SL61', 'B008');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG58', '65 Lori St', 'Burmingham', 'BR22DZ', 'Flat ', 3, 500, 'CO63', 'SL51', 'B010');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG59', '25 River Dr', 'Londo', 'YZ32DC', 'House ', 8, 1400, 'CO63', 'SA10', 'B009');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG71', '23 Lori St', 'Burmingham', 'BR22DZ', 'Flat ', 3, 500, 'CO63', 'SL51', 'B010');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG74', '304 Michelle St', 'Burmingham', 'BR29ZS', 'House ', 3, 600, 'CO51', 'SL51', 'B010');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG76', '7 Dracula St', 'Londo', 'OP32DC', 'Flat ', 3, 400, 'CO64', 'SA8', 'B008');
INSERT INTO property_for_rent (propertyno, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerno, staffno, branchno) VALUES ('PG78', '9 Thames Dr', 'Londo', 'JA32DC', 'House ', 4, 700, 'CO64', 'SG17', 'B010');

INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SA10', 'Bria', 'Sothe', 'Supervisor', 'M', '1964-12-30', 17000.00, 'B008');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SA5', 'Mark', 'Smith', 'Assistant', 'M', '1974-11-23',10000.00, 'B008');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SA8', 'Jake', 'Austi', 'Assistant', 'M', '1979-01-03', 9000.00, 'B009');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SG15', 'Angila', 'Jolee', 'Assistant', 'F', '1976-09-23', 12000.00, 'B010');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SG16', 'Fredo ', 'Satin ', 'Supervisor', 'M', '1973-04-13', 16000.00, 'B010');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SG17', 'Gyneth', 'Paltrow', 'Assistant', 'F', '1980-01-07', 11000.00, 'B010');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SL51', 'Maria', 'Bria', 'Assistant', 'F', '1976-10-15', 13000.00, 'B009');
INSERT INTO staff (staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno) VALUES ('SL61', 'Sheela', 'Johnso', 'Manager', 'F', '1969-02-20',33000.00, 'B009');

TRUNCATE TABLE viewing ;
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR78', 'PG71', '1993-06-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR78', 'PG57', '1985-02-01', 'We will go for it');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR79', 'PG57', '2002-01-01', 'Wonderful');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR79', 'PG76', '2002-10-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR79', 'PG74', '1999-10-01','Wonderful');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR79', 'PG15', '1995-06-01','Can you change the color');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR83', 'PG15', '2000-12-01','Wonderful');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR78', 'PG59', '1999-10-01', 'It is good');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR78', 'PG76', '1995-03-02', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR79', 'PG59', '1998-01-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR80', 'PG58', '1979-12-01', 'It is good');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR80', 'PG15', '1985-01-01', 'Let us think about it');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR81', 'PG15', '1996-01-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR81', 'PG59', '2001-06-01', 'I want to rent it ASAP');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR82', 'PG58', '2001-01-15', 'I like the kitchen the most');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR83', 'PG58', '2002-10-15', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR83', 'PG56', '1999-11-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR84', 'PG15', '1995-04-15', 'It is good');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR85', 'PG15', '2002-06-01', 'I like the kitchen the most');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR85', 'PG59', '2001-11-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR86', 'PG59', '1997-11-01', NULL);
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR87', 'PG56', '2001-12-01', 'I want to rent it ASAP');
INSERT INTO viewing (clientno, propertyno, viewdate, comments) VALUES ('CR87', 'PG59', '1999-04-01', 'I like the kitchen the most');

ALTER TABLE LEASE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LEASE_CLIENT FOREIGN KEY(CLIENT_NO)
REFERENCES CLIENT (CLIENTNO)
;
ALTER TABLE LEASE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LEASE_PROPERTY_FOR_RENT FOREIGN KEY(PROPERTY_NO)
REFERENCES PROPERTY_FOR_RENT (PROPERTYNO)
;
ALTER TABLE PROPERTY_FOR_RENT ADD FOREIGN KEY(BRANCHNO)
REFERENCES BRANCH (BRANCHNO);

ALTER TABLE PROPERTY_FOR_RENT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PROPERTYFORRENTPRIVATEOWNER FOREIGN KEY(OWNERNO)
REFERENCES PRIVATE_OWNER (OWNERNO)
;
ALTER TABLE REGISTRATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTRATION_BRANCH FOREIGN KEY(BRANCHNO)
REFERENCES BRANCH (BRANCHNO)
;
ALTER TABLE REGISTRATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTRATION_CLIENT FOREIGN KEY(CLIENTNO)
REFERENCES CLIENT (CLIENTNO)
;
ALTER TABLE REGISTRATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REGISTRATION_STAFF FOREIGN KEY(STAFFNO)
REFERENCES STAFF (STAFFNO)
;
ALTER TABLE STAFF ADD FOREIGN KEY(BRANCHNO)
REFERENCES BRANCH (BRANCHNO)
;
ALTER TABLE VIEWING ADD CONSTRAINT FK_VIEWING_CLIENT FOREIGN KEY(CLIENTNO)
REFERENCES CLIENT (CLIENTNO)
;

ALTER TABLE VIEWING ADD CONSTRAINT FK_VIEWING_PROPERTY_FOR_RENT FOREIGN KEY(PROPERTYNO)
REFERENCES PROPERTY_FOR_RENT (PROPERTYNO)
;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: How can you drop something that doesn't exist?